# Is it possible for me to use a repository I've defined in an MVC project, from a Windows Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

The folder structure of my entire project is like

```
MySolution
   MyWindowsService
      bin 
      obj
      .
      .
      ClassThatDefinesMyService.cs
      ClassThatContainsMain.cs
   MyMVCProject
      App_Data
      .
      .
      Repositories
      .
         ThingMyRepository.cs
      .
   packages
      .
      .
      .
   MySolution.sln
```

and my Windows Service is something that performs work for my MVC project while it is running (and the service is started in the `App_Start` of the MVC project). I've created my model from the database and `ThingMyRepository.cs` is what I want to use as an interface for the database. However, when I call one of its methods from within `ClassThatDefinesMyService.cs` I'm getting the error

> No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with
>   invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is
>   registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config
>   file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more
>   information.

This was after I got a different error that I fixed by copying a `connectionString` from the `web.config` in my MVC project into the `app.config` in my service. Anyways, I'm wondering whether I might be going down a rabbit hole with trying to use that repository to connection to the database. How can I fix this? Or should I completely re-architect it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply move your repository to a separate project (interface & implementation), and reference this DAL project in your service, instead of referencing the website.

As long as you don't have references to httpcontext or other web specific objects in your repository (which you really shouldn't have), things will be fine

As you discovered, you'll need to add the configuration in the service project config too.